# How to read array from XML using xmllint

Tags: arrays, xml, bash, xmllint

I have below xml, where I need to get values "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

```
    <Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
        <Array id="includedCipherSuites" type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</Item>
            <Item>TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384</Item>
            <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384</Item>
        </Array>
    
        <Array  id= "includedProtocols" type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>TLSv1.2</Item>
            <Item>TLSv1.3</Item>
        </Array> 
   </Configure>
```

I tried, below.

> $xmllint --xpath '//Configure/Array/@id' jetty.xml
> id="includedCipherSuites" id="includedProtocols"
>
> xmllint --xpath '//Configure/Array[0]/@id' jetty.xml
> XPath set is empty
>
> xmllint --xpath '//Configure/Array[2]/@id' jetty.xml
> id="includedProtocols"

I am not sure how to read Item from the array with id=includedCipherSuites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indices are 1-based. So, use `Array[1]` to address the right array item, then continue traversing down. `text()` will give you the element contents.

```bash
xmllint --xpath '//Configure/Array[1]/Item/text()' jetty.xml
```

Or use `Array[@id="includedCipherSuites"]` to select by attribute value:

```bash
xmllint --xpath '//Configure/Array[@id="includedCipherSuites"]/Item/text()' jetty.xml
```

Output:

```xml
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works as expected. Is is possible to have any separators?

I am trying this, but don't want to have , at front

xmllint --xpath '//Configure/Array[@id="includedCipherSuites"]/Item/text()' jetty.xml
 | sed 's/TLS_/,TLS_/g'

,TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Comment: Below one works. 

xmllint --xpath '//Configure/Array[@id="includedCipherSuites"]/Item/text()' jetty.xml | sed -e 's/TLS_/,TLS_/g' -e 's/,TLS_/TLS_/1'

Comment: @Bala Yes, you need external tools as XPath is about extracting data, not formatting it. Although XPath 2.0 implements `string-join` to concatenate using a glue string, but `xmllint` only supports XPath 1.0. An external tool could either post-process your `xmllint` output (`awk` or `sed` are fine, I'd prefer `xmllint … | paste -sd ,`), or be used for the entire process (eg. [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/): `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//Configure/Array[1]/Item' -v . -i "position() < 3" -o ,` or [xq](https://github.com/sibprogrammer/xq) `xq -r '.Configure.Array[0].Item | join(",")'`)